# Bad Twitter streaming request: 401 twit

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to connect to a twitter stream, but I keep  receiving this error

> Bad Twitter streaming request: 401

I'm pretty sure that my keys are correct. Any suggestions?

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var t = new Twit({
consumer_key:'MYKEY',
consumer_secret:'SECRET',
    app_only_auth: true
});

var stream = t.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'twitter' });

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
   console.log(tweet);
})

stream.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add **access_token** and **access_token_secret**. [Look](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)